# Why use git bash for windows

Tags: git, git-bash

Recently I started a wordpress course on Windows where we used node + git bash + gulp to automatically reload the page.
In my previous course I was using only node + live server which I found quicker & less confusing.

Could someone please explain what is the use of git bash as surely, we could do that without using it?
I cannot find any quick and specific explanation what is git bash actually helping with.

Comment: It seems to be difficult to grasp what exactly you're asking. git bash is just a tool, and a very efficient one. What problem do you have it doesn't solve?

Comment: git bash is usually just a substitute for a linux CLI on Windows systems. It's a rough workaround that includes core utilities available on Linux that are not available on windows. Windows does not have a succinct and powerful command line interface (CLI), so people will often use git bash as replacement

Comment: Git bash is, well, a port of [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) which is a ubiquitous shell found on GNU/Linux-based operating systems (Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora/CentOS etc) and Mac OS X, so quite some many people coming from these OSes to work on Windows _feel at home_ when they have access to `bash`. Git for Windows also makes available a set of command-line tools which are not "part of" bash but are routinely used _with_ it.

Comment: Note that while these CLI tools are available right from Git Bash, you can also make them available to the native Windows shells—such as `cmd.exe` and Powershell—during the installation of GfW—it explicitly asks about that. The bottom line is that no, Git Bash it not in any way required for _interacting with Git_ (though it's used by parts of Git itself internally) but _subjectively_ it may make the developer more productive (or may not, YMMV).

Answer (score 3):

Git bash is only a terminal giving you the ability to use the command line. You could also use Window's CMD and it would be the same.